# JSF2+AJAX: Keep Scrollbar position, plain mojarra

Tags: jsf-2

I have a more complex webapp in JSF2 (+EJB3.1 +JPA2 on glassfish 3.1), which only uses standard (mojarra) JSF-components and makes massive use of nested composites and ajax-calls.

I want all my scrollbars save and restore their position whenever an ajax-call occurs.

I tried different approaches, but none seems really good to me, so I need some hints which way to go:

1) JavaScript:

Add a JavaScript which reads all scrollbar-positions either when a scroll occurs (element.onScroll must be set by javascript, cause this attribute is not available in XHTML4) or when an ajax-request occurs (jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(savePositions)).
Save the scrollbars' positions either in hidden input-fields or in cookie.
Restore them when the ajax-response occurs (jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(restorePositions)).

Contras if not using cookies:

-The scroll position must be stored in the hidden input field before the ajax-request occurs, so the element.onScroll-attribute must be used here. Not really nice, cause it saves the positions many many times, although one time before each ajax-request would be sufficient.

-All hidden input fields must be transferred in the ajax-call. Since the JSF-site uses several forms, there seems no way to automatically add them to all ajax-calls. Instead every  element needs the hidden input fields added to the execute-attribute.

-One hidden input field is needed for every scrollable element.

Contra if using cookies:

-well, cookies need to be enabled for the website.

Contra in general:

-JavaScript code must either know or iterate through all elements, which have scrollbars.

-JavaScript code must be executed again, if a componenent is re-rendered and needs the onScroll-attribute set.

2) JavaScript + Composite:

So I thought of writing a composite scrollStateSave, which points to the JSF-id of the element, which has the scrollbars. The composite contains the hidden input field (or cookie) and javascript and handles everything, so I just need to add one "instance" of the composite per element, which has scrollbars. The javascript makes use of closures to work for multiple elements on one site.

Contra:

-The javascript inside the composite is not executed on a re-render after an ajax-call. There are workarounds for this, but they look ugly to me.

3) Myfaces has an option AUTO_SCROLL:

How does it work exactly? Does it work for non-myfaces-jsf-components?

4) Tomahawk offers a t:autoScroll-behaviour:

Using the tomahawk-replacements for the standard-mojarra-jsf2-components would be ok for me. But documentation of t:autoscroll speaks of an attribute "event", while implementation needs attribute "value". What should I put in this attribute to make t:autoScrolll work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I finished solution 2 and it is working quite nicely. In order to give other developers some help and in order to get hints, which parts of my solution could be better, I will post the code.

Composite /WebContent/resources/components/scrollbarStateSaver.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<h:body>

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="for"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputScript name="scrollbars.js" library="js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        saveScrollbarPos("#{cc.attrs.for}");
    </script>
</composite:implementation>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Javascript /WebContent/resources/js/scrollbar.js:

```
function saveScrollbarPos(id) {
var scrollbarid = id;

function savePos() {
    var scrollbar = document.getElementById(scrollbarid);
    document.cookie = scrollbarid+".scrolltop="+scrollbar.scrollTop+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function restorePos() {
    var scrollbar = document.getElementById(scrollbarid);
    scrollbar.scrollTop = readCookie(scrollbarid+".scrolltop");
}

function onStatusChange(data) {
    var status = data.status;
    if (status == "begin") {
        savePos();
    }
    else {
        restorePos();
    }
};

var scrollbar = document.getElementById(scrollbarid);
if (scrollbar != null) {
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(onStatusChange);
    jsf.ajax.addOnError(onStatusChange);
}
};
```

Small example xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <div id="panel" style="overflow:auto;">
            long content with ajax-calls in it
        </div>
        <c:scrollbarStateSaver for="panel"/>

        <h:panelGroup id="panel" style="overflow:auto;">
            long content with ajax-calls in it
        </h:panelGroup>
        <c:scrollbarStateSaver for="form:panel"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Of course, the composite could be enhanced to calculate the jsf-id via #{cc.parent} and #{cc.clientId} itself, then the for-attribute of the composite could handle jsf-ids, if the composite is inserted on the same level as the h:panelGroup.

The JavaScript can also probably be solved better, but it actually was some of my first javascript ever.